# How to reference the name of the table used by GraphQL models in Amplify when calling a DynamoDB in Lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am trying to set up GraphQL api with AWS Amplify. The docs provide the solution to call a DynamoDB from a Lambda function in Python:

```
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

def handler(event, context):
  data = client.scan(
    TableName='your-table-name'
  )

  response = {
      'statusCode': 200,
      'body': json.dumps(data),
      'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      },
  }

  return response
```

What I can't figure out is how to reference the name of the table used by GraphQL models in Amplify to put it in `TableName='your-table-name'` (so that it works both for cloud version and mock). Any ideas?

Edit: solved by updating the function with the permissions to read/edit the table. The table could then be referenced using an environmental variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by updating the function with the permissions to read/edit the table. The table could then be referenced using an environmental variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got your issue, but trying to reference the table sounds not the best option here.

Take a look at this post from AWS that shows how to runs amplify locally through the `amplify mock api`
https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/mobile/amplify-framework-local-mocking/

Comment: I know how to mock the api locally, but it doesn't solve my problem. Why is trying to reference the table not the best option here? Is there any other way to modify the objects in the database from within the lambda function?